# Probability Question on Speed Dating

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have 2 groups of 20 people. 20 Male and 20 Female.

After doing some speed dating, each Man writes down 2 women he fancies. And Each women writes down 2 men she fancies. Everybody has a uniform probability to like anyone else.

I consider it a 'Match' when a man and women put down each other on their respective lists.

**What is the probability that exactly 5 matches occur?** 
Again assuming there is a uniform distribution of who people 'like' each other (each person has the same probability to like each other person).

I've coded a simulation and ultimately the probability converges to roughly 17.3%

But I am having a hard time rectifying the solution in a theoretical sense though. Would love any help!

Another note: given the inherent 'pick and replace' nature of the liking process. I believe it is roughly 39/380 for a given man M to like female F (and vice versa)

EDIT: ONLY MEN LIKE WOMEN AND VICE VERSA. It is a separate problem for same gender. An interesting one I agree. But my question is 'hetero-centric'.

Comment: The probability for a given male to like a given female is $\frac1{10}$, since by symmetry and linearity of expectation this must be $\frac1{20}$ of the expected number of females he likes, which is $2$. The question itself seems rather difficult.

Comment: The probability for a given male to like a given female is not 1/10 as far as I understand it.

He has a 1/20 chance of liking any of the females. However on his second 'pick' he must choose from only 19 remaining. His 'second favorite' so to speak.

So instead of it being 1/20 + 1/20 = 1/10
It is 1/20 + 1/19 = 39/380 ~ 1/10 (but not exactly)


The question itself is quite difficult in my opinion. Hence why I am hoping for help.

Comment: It's equally interesting to consider same-gender speed dating, where all participants really can fancy all other participants. (The OP writes "everybody has a uniform probability to like anyone else", but the context makes me think that the OP intends males to like only females and vice versa.)

Comment: There are $\binom{20}2$ possible pairs of likes for a given woman. Of them, $\binom{19}1$ of them contain any particular man. Therefore the probability she likes that particlar man is $\binom{19}1/\binom{20}2=\frac1{10}$. One could also argue by symmetry.

Comment: @WilliamCalhoun: That reasoning is flawed. The given female has a $\frac1{20}$ chance of being the first pick and a $\frac1{20}$ chance of being the second pick. The fact that another female was previously chosen as the first pick doesn't reduce the chance on the second pick. I suggest that you take the time to follow the argument I gave for the result $\frac1{10}$, since these things are usually far easier to get right using symmetry and linearity of expectation than by concrete calculations.

Comment: The flaw in @WilliamCalhoun's calculation in the comment: the $1/19$ is the probability of being chosen, *conditional* on not being chosen the first time. The probability of being chosen as "second favorite" is still exactly $1/20$.

Comment: @Greg Martin
I agree that the probability is 1/20 for any women on any pick.
The issue is that if I pick Women 1 on my first pick (1/20 chance).
Then on the second pick I pick women 1 again (1/20 chance), I need to pick again. So I pick again at random (1/20 chance for everyone again), however I am only picking from a pool of 19 the second time. So it is really 1/19. 

I am open to being wrong but I think that logically makes sense. Could someone explain how it is not slightly conditional? It seems that way to me.

Comment: @jorki
You can't pick the same person twice. Therefore your first pick does have some conditional impact, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Is it two matches when both of a particular persons choices also choose that person? Or is that only one match?

Comment: @Joffan
It is a match when Male M picks Female F and Female F picks Male M.

Comment: I understood that. What I am asking is, if M7 picks F1 and F4, and both F1 and F4 have M7 as one of their picks, is that 2 matches? Even though there is only one man involved?

Comment: That should be two matches.

Comment: @WilliamCalhoun: you are right that the probability that you pick Woman 2 (say) on your second pick, *given that you didn't pick her on the first pick*, is $1/19$. That is a conditional probability, by definition. If you still don't think your logic is wrong, consider this: applying the same logic to the situation where there are only two women in the speed dating pool, you would calculate that the probability of choosing any given woman is $\frac12+\frac11=\frac32$, which is certainly wrong.

Comment: @GregMartin. That makes sense in the simple example why its wrong. Thanks.

So the probability of Man M choosing Women F is 1/10
Probability that Man M chooses Women F and Women F chooses Man M is therefore 1/100

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a somewhat more general problem, where there are $m$ males and $n$ females: each male is allowed two choices, but each female may be allowed $0$, $1$ or $2$ choices; there are $n_0$, $n_1$ and $n_2$ females allowed $0$, $1$ or $2$ choices respectively.  Let $P_k(m,n_0,n_1,n_2)$ be the probability of exactly $k$ matches in this situation.  We condition on who the last male chooses, and who chooses the last male.
He makes two choices, say $j_1$ and $j_2$.  Meanwhile each female with $f_j = 2$ chooses him with probability $2/n$, while each female with $f_j = 1$ chooses him with probability $1/n$, and of course females with $f_j = 0$ can't choose him.  We count the number of matches involving this male, and then we are in a situation with one less male, and where the females who chose male $n$ have one fewer choice.  This gives us a recursion for $P_k(m,n_0,n_1,n_2)$.

Using Maple, it took a few minutes to compute $P_5(20,0,0,20) = 0.1732445697$.
Here's my Maple code:

```
P:= proc(k, m, n0, n1, n2) option remember; 
local n, x0, x1, x2,  y1, y2, t,px0,px1,py1,py2,pz1,pz2,pz;  
if k < 0 or n1 + 2*n2 < k or 2*m < k then return 0 
elif m = 0 or n1 + 2*n2 = 0 then return 1.0 
fi;
t:= 0; n:= n0 + n1 + n2;
for x0 from 0 to min(n0,2) do 
  px0 :=  binomial(n0,x0)*binomial(n-n0,2-x0)*2/n/(n-1);
  for x1 from max(0,2-x0-n2) to min(n1,2-x0) do
    x2:= 2-x0-x1;
    px1:= px0 * binomial(n1,x1)*binomial(n2,x2)/binomial(n1+n2,2-x0);
    for y1 from 0 to n1 do
      py1:= px1*binomial(n1,y1)*(1/m)^y1*(1-1/m)^(n1-y1);
      if py1 = 0 then next fi;
      pz1:= [seq(binomial(y1,z)*binomial(n1-y1,x1-z)/binomial(n1,x1),z=0..2)];
      for y2 from 0 to n2 do
        py2:= py1*binomial(n2,y2)*(2/m)^y2*(1-2/m)^(n2-y2);
        if py2 = 0 then next fi;
        pz2:= [seq(binomial(y2,z)*binomial(n2-y2,x2-z)/binomial(n2,x2),z=0..2)];
        pz:= pz1[1]*pz2[1];
        if pz > 0 then t:= t + py2*pz* procname(k,m-1,n0+y1,n1-y1+y2,n2-y2) fi;
        pz:= pz1[2]*pz2[1]+pz1[1]*pz2[2];
        if pz > 0 then t:= t + py2*pz* procname(k-1,m-1,n0+y1,n1-y1+y2,n2-y2) fi;
        pz:= pz1[3]*pz2[1]+pz1[2]*pz2[2]+pz1[1]*pz2[3];
        if pz > 0 then t:= t + py2*pz* procname(k-2,m-1,n0+y1,n1-y1+y2,n2-y2) fi;
        od
    od
  od
od;
t; 
end proc;
```

Answer (score 0):

The probability that a given man (m) matches with exactly 1 woman (w) is given by $P_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{19} P(m\:chooses\:w\:\cap k\: w\:chooses\:m)$.

The probability that k women choose a given man is: $\binom{20}{k}\big(\frac{1}{10}\big)^{k}\big(\frac{9}{10}\big)^{20-k}$, while the probability that the man chooses exactly one woman in that scenario is $\frac{k}{20}+\frac{20-k}{20}\frac{k}{19}$. So the probability that a man matches with exactly 1 woman can be evaluated as $$P_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{19}\Big(\frac{k}{20}+\frac{20-k}{20}\frac{k}{19}\Big)\Big[\binom{20}{k}\Big(\frac{1}{10}\Big)^{k}\Big(\frac{9}{10}\Big)^{20-k}\Big]$$ = 0.19

The probability that a given man matches with exactly 2 women can be calculated in a similar fashion:

$$P_2 = \sum_{k=2}^{20}\Big(\frac{k}{20}\frac{k-1}{19}\Big)\Big[\binom{20}{k}\Big(\frac{1}{10}\Big)^{k}\Big(\frac{9}{10}\Big)^{20-k}\Big]$$ = 0.01

The probability that a man does not get any matches is then given by $1-P_1-P_2$.

To have exactly five matches, there are three cases to consider.

Case 1: Five men each match with exactly one woman. The probability for this case is: $$\binom{20}{5}{P_1}^5(1-P_1-P_2)^{15}$$

Case 2: Three men each match with exactly one woman, and one man matches with two women. The probability for this case is: $$\binom{20}{3}{P_1}^3 17 P_2 (1-P_1-P_2)^{16}$$

Case 3: One man matches with one woman, and two men match with two women. The probability for this case is: $$20 P_1 \binom{19}{2} {P_2}^2 (1-P_1-P_2)^{17}$$

Summing the probabilities from each case, we find that the total probability of five matches is 0.17395.

Comment: You're treating events involving different men as independent,  but they aren't.

Comment: @RobertIsrael - can you elaborate?

Comment: For example, case 1.  Given that man #1 matches with one woman, we know that woman has chosen man #1, while some other woman (the other one man #1 chose) did not choose man #1.  This changes the probabilities for man #2 to get a match.

Comment: Maybe easier to see in a more extreme case.  Suppose there are three men and two women.  Then $P_2 = 4/9$, $P_1 = 4/9$, $P_0 = 1/9$ are the probabilities of a given man having $2$, $1$ or $0$ matches.  But there will always be exactly $4$ matches.  Your method would give positive probabilities to anything from $0$ to $6$ matches.

Comment: Ah, I see. But for larger groups the probabilities approach independent events, which is why this method seems to be accurate for groups of 20. So is there a theoretical way of solving the problem with conditional probabilities?

Comment: Yes: see my answer.